# how to test something in nsthread

Tags: ios, ocunit

I want to use OCUnit to test my work. 
but one of my methodes is like this:

```
- (BOOL)testThread
{
    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(thread) object:nil];
    [thread start];

    return YES;
}

- (void)thread
{
    NSLog(@"thread**********************");
    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(thread2) object:nil];
    [thread start];
}

- (void)thread2
{
    NSLog(@"thread2**********************");
}
```

Now I want to run the test:

```
- (void)testExample
{
    testNSThread *_testNSThread = [[testNSThread alloc] init];
    STAssertTrue([_testNSThread testThread], @"test");
}
```

in my test case
but the thread2 dose not run
so,what should I do? 3Q!

Comment: I know this is just a code sample and has nothing to do with your question, but don't use thisNotation but ThisNotation when naming classes - The first letter should be always uppercase. Also, the underscore in local variable names is not appropriate, it is used normally for instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dispatch_semaphore` to make `testThread` wait until `thread2` has completed:

```
@interface MyTests () {
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
}

@implementation MyTests 

- (void)setUp 
{
    [super setUp];
    semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
}

- (BOOL)testThread
{
    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(thread) object:nil];
    [thread start];

    // Wait until the semaphore is signaled
    while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)thread
{
    NSLog(@"thread**********************");
    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(thread2) object:nil];
    [thread start];
}

- (void)thread2
{
    NSLog(@"thread2**********************");

    // Signal the semaphore to release the wait lock
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}

@end
```